# Countif multiple criteria

Tags: excel, countif

Im trying to figure out some numbers of cases in excel;
The cases has both an analyst and an advisor - and some cases has an advisor from the same team as the analyst.

I need to know how many case where the advisor is from our team, where the analyst isn't.

So far i've used this formula `=COUNTIFS(Data!$A$2:$A$17;"<>"&AG2;Data!$A$2:$A$17;AQ2)`

DATA!A2:A17 = list of names

AG = name of analyst

AQ = name of advisor

The issues is that it shows advisor cases where the analyst is still representet in the datasheet

Comment: Hi please edit the question on which language is belongs too.helpful to help.

Comment: e.g. Excel? if so it is editted now

Comment: Now understood the question on which you need answer is excel. further request is please share some sample data.